# Adding drop down menu to image button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add an input image button into my html which when clicked will give a drop down menu with three  input range bars (input type = "range"). 
how can I do this using html,css, javascript?

Answer (score 0):

What you have to is to use jquery make your picture and form and then apply this jquery script and it will show and hide the range inputs.

```js
$("#under").hide();
$("#clicker").click(function() {
  $("#under").toggle();
});
```

```css
.under {
  position: absolute;
}
#clicker {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x75" id="clicker" />
<div class="under" id="under">
  <input type="range" />
  <br />
  <input type="range" />
  <br />
  <input type="range" />
  <br />
</div>
```

i've made a jsfiddle for it: https://jsfiddle.net/a6ry2j4s/

Comment: This is not a drop down menu, it justs hides and shows div element with three inputs, I'll have to position this div element exactly below my clicker to make it resemble to a drop down menu and I want to avoid this method..is there any way that could create it through a more specific method designed for this only.